# Kubernetes: validating update requests to custom resource

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-custom-resources

I created a custom resource definition (CRD) and its controller in my cluster, now I can create custom resources, but how do I validate update requests to the CR? e.g., only certain fields can be updated.

Answer (score 3):

The Kubernetes docs on Custom Resources has a section on [Advanced features and flexibility](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/#advanced-features-and-flexibility) (never mind that validating requests should be considered a pretty basic feature ). For validation of CRDs, it says:

> Most validation can be specified in the CRD using [OpenAPI v3.0 validation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/extend-api-custom-resource-definitions/#validation). Any other validations supported by addition of a [Validating Webhook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#validatingadmissionwebhook-alpha-in-1-8-beta-in-1-9).

The OpenAPI v3.0 validation won't help you accomplish what you're looking for, namely ensuring immutability of certain fields on your custom resource, it's only helpful for stateless validations where you're looking at one instance of an object and determining if it's valid or not, you can't compare it to a previous version of the resource and validate that nothing has changed.

You could use Validating Webhooks. It feels like a heavyweight solution, as you will need to implement a server that conforms to the Validating Webhook contract (responding to specific kinds of requests with specific kinds of responses), but you will have the required data at least to make the desired determination, e.g. knowing that it's an UPDATE request and knowing what the old object looked like.  For more details, see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#webhook-request-and-response). I have not actually tried Validating Webhooks, but it feels like it could work.

An alternative approach I've used is to store the user-provided data within the `Status` subresource of the custom resource the first time it's created, and then always look at the data there. Any changes to the `Spec` are ignored, though your controller can notice discrepancies between what's in the `Spec` and what's in the `Status`, and embed a warning in the `Status` telling the user that they've mutated the object in an invalid way and their specified values are being ignored. You can see an example of that approach [here](https://github.com/amitkgupta/boshv3/blob/e037d2ddddc440004e169869b6143ff8bdd0f84e/api/v1/team_types.go#L76-L94) and [here](https://github.com/amitkgupta/boshv3/blob/01f6a62151a6df8e524241d4a14b08dae195f431/controllers/team_controller.go#L55-L60).  As per the [relevant README section](https://github.com/amitkgupta/boshv3#team-1) of that linked repo, this results in the following behaviour:

> The `AVAILABLE` column will show false if the UAA client for the team has not been successfully created. The `WARNING` column will display a warning if you have mutated the Team spec after initial creation. The `DIRECTOR` column displays the originally provided value for `spec.director` and this is the value that this team will continue to use. If you do attempt to mutate the `Team` resource, you can see your (ignored) user-provided value with the `-o wide` flag:
>
> ```
> $ kubectl get team --all-namespaces -owide
> NAMESPACE   NAME   DIRECTOR     AVAILABLE   WARNING   USER-PROVIDED DIRECTOR
> test        test   vbox-admin   true                  vbox-admin
> ```
>
> If we attempt to mutate the `spec.director` property, here's what we will see:
>
> ```
> $ kubectl get team --all-namespaces -owide
> NAMESPACE   NAME   DIRECTOR     AVAILABLE   WARNING                                              USER-PROVIDED DIRECTOR
> test        test   vbox-admin   true        API resource has been mutated; all changes ignored   bad-new-director-name
> ```

Comment: Thanks, but how do you implement "Any changes to the Spec are ignored"? I assume when your validation logic is called (maybe by watch API), the spec has already been updated.

Comment: In my controller logic, I ignore the values in the Spec. When my controller handles a request, it checks whether there are relevant values in the Status subresource. If not, it knows that this is the initial creation and copies the immutable values from the Spec to the Status, and persists the custom resource. From there on out, for any requests that it handles, it pulls those values from the Status subresource rather than from what's in the Spec.  The Spec still gets changed (the only way to prevent that is with a Validating Webhook), but my controller ignores those values.